# ¿Por que no puedo validar este formulario?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

No encuentro el error acá porque no lo manda al correo que esta declarado en action

```js
function validar() {

  if (valor = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (valor == null || valor.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(valor)) {
      return false;
    }) {

    alert('Error Debe ingresar texto y no espacios en blanco');
    return false;
  } else if (valor = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    if (!(/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)/.test(valor))) {
      return false;
    }) {

    alert('[ERROR] El campo solicita un mail valido');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
html {
  background: url(guitarra.jpeg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

#feedback-page {
  text-align: center;
}

#form-main {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

#form-div {
  background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.4);
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -260px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}

.feedback-input {
  color: #3c3c3c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.feedback-input:focus {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: 3px solid #3498db;
  color: #3498db;
  outline: none;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
}

.focused {
  color: #30aed6;
  border: #30aed6 solid 3px;
}


/* Icons ---------------------------------- */

#name {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#name:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 8px 5px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#comment {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150%;
  resize: vertical;
}

input:hover,
textarea:hover,
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

#button-blue {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#button-blue:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #0493bd;
}

.submit:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}

.ease {
  width: 0px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.submit:hover .ease {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  #form-div {
    left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="form-div">
  <form id="Formulario" action="pepito123@gmail.com" method="post" onsubmit="return validar(this)  >    
      <p class=" name ">
        <input name="name " type="text " class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input " placeholder="Name " id="name " />
      </p>
      
      <p class="email ">
        <input name="email " type="text " class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input " id="email " placeholder="Email " />
      </p>
      
      <p class="text ">
        <textarea name="text " ></textarea>
      </p>
      
      
      <div class="submit ">
        <input type="submit " value="SEND " id="button-blue "/>
        <div class="ease "></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que hay bastantes errores.

En el HTML:

- te falta cerrar las comillas del atributo onsubmit
- La función validar no recibe parámetros por lo que debería ser onsubmit="return validar();"
- En el type del botón de envío te sobra un espacio (debería ser type="submit")
- También te sobra un espacio en el id del input del nombre (debería ser id="name")

En el javascript:

- la declaración de la variable valor no deberías incluirla en un if
- Es recomendable que las comparaciones las hagas con === en lugar de == (excepto en el caso del null si quieres contemplar el caso de que el valor pueda ser undefined)
- Las llaves y los paréntesis de cierre no coinciden con los de apertura.
- El alert que muestra el mensaje de error debe estar antes de la instrucción return false
- Si la validación es correcta deberías devolver un true.

El javascript debería quedarte algo así:

```js
function validar() {
  var valor = document.getElementById("name").value;

  if (valor == null || valor.length === 0 || /^\s+$/.test(valor)) {
   alert('Error Debe ingresar texto y no espacios en blanco');
      return false;
  }
  if (!(/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)/.test(valor))) {
      alert('[ERROR] El campo solicita un mail valido');
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A ver, ya en el principio del script de javascript tienes un error, fijate en esta línea. Tienes un lío entre llaves y corchete

```
if (valor = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

No cierras el valor del IF.